# sql select last record notes for each stundents

Tags: sql

I have this table notes.[data of my table note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18arn.png)
and i want to select last notes for each subject(matiere) and for each students(id_etudiant).
please help me with my sql code.
In short i want result like this [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZbmB.png)

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show your efforts (and read [ask])

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Answer (score 0):

You can try query like this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name GROUP BY id_etudiant,id_matiere ORDER BY cod_note desc
```

Comment: not working. i want the last (code_note) for each subject and for each students.. my solution now is :select n1.* from notes n1 left join notes n2 ON (n1.id_etudiant= n2.id_etudiant and n1.id_matiere=n2.id_matiere 
and n1.code_note< n2.code_note) where n2.code_note is null;

Answer (score 0):

i will explain. i have a table "notes" like this:

**code    id   id_sub   id_unit  notes      session     year** 
1     BEE12   1         1      10.00      normale     2017
2     ABHA    1         1      9.00       normale     2017
3     BEE12   2         1      13.00      normale     2017
4     ABHA    2         1      10.00      normale     2017
5     ABHA    1         1      19.00      rattrapage  2017

but i need a query who return this:

**code    id   id_sub   id_unit  notes      session     year** 
1     BEE12   1         1      10.00      normale     2017
3     BEE12   2         1      13.00      normale     2017
4     ABHA    2         1      10.00      normale     2017
5     ABHA    1         1      19.00      rattrapage  2017

I use this query now: 
**select n1.* from notes n1 left join notes n2 ON (n1.id= n2.id and n1.id_sub=n2.id_sub
and n1.code < n2.code) where n2.code is null;**

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple.
*select* is used to display content, So whatever you want to be displayed first we can alter that by using *order by* with that coloumn and sort data in ascending or descending order.

try query:

**select * from table_name order by id DESC**

Comment: here id is the coloumn_name by which we want to sort